# Como impedir que seja escrito '\n' na consola

Tags: c++

Olá, eu tenho este código:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

bool gotoxy(const WORD x, const WORD y) {
    COORD xy;
    xy.X = x;
    xy.Y = y;
    return SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), xy);
}

int main() {
    system("MODE CON COLS=20 LINES=30");
    gotoxy(0, 29);
    for(int i=0; i < 20; ++i) {
        cout << "a";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Este código funciona plenamente, com um problema: os caaracteres 'a' não são impressos na última linha, mas sim na penúltima. Eu acho que este comportamento é devido a uma quebra de linha que é inserida. Alguém sabe uma maneira para contornar este comportamento? Obrigado!

Comment: A ultima linha é na verdade o `input`, não? Aonde o usuário vai digitar algo, então creio que não faça sentido escrever algo no input (ou se não for o usuário, seria aonde o ponteiro parou). Se entendi o seu problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esta pergunta foi respondida no chat [Estouro de Pilha](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha).
No chat foi-me indicada a função `WriteConsoleOutputA` que, passo a citar:

> WriteConsoleOutput has no effect on the cursor position.

O que quer dizer que esta função não interfere com a posição do cursor.
Aqui está um exemplo de como se usa esta função, de acordo com a pergunta inicial:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "windows.h"
#include "unistd.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
    system("MODE CON COLS=40 LINES=30");
    HANDLE wHnd;
    int i;
    CHAR_INFO charInfo[40];

    wHnd = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    // play with these values 
    COORD charBufSize = {40, 1};         // do not exceed x*y=100 !!!
    COORD characterPos = {0, 0};        // must be within 0 and x*y=100
    SMALL_RECT writeArea = {0, 29, 39, 39};


    for (i = 0; i < (40); i++) {
        charInfo[i].Char.AsciiChar = ' ';
        charInfo[i].Attributes = BACKGROUND_GREEN | BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_BLUE | BACKGROUND_INTENSITY;
    }

    WriteConsoleOutputA(wHnd, charInfo, charBufSize, characterPos, &writeArea);
    sleep(5);
    return 0;
}
```